# router outlet empty after logout angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I work on an angular2 application with login an logout and i have a different layout for log page and the others pages.

This is the html of the app component

```
<div *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn()" class="log">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()">
  <app-header></app-header>

  <section class="layout">
    <!-- sidebar menu -->

    <aside class="sidebar canvas-left">
      <!-- main navigation -->
      <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
      <!-- /main navigation -->
    </aside>
    <!-- /sidebar menu -->

    <!-- main content -->
    <section class="main-content">
      <div class="content-wrap no-padding">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

this is my route config

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'my-company', component:MyCompanyComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path:'my-web-supports', component:MyWebSupportsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path:'my-statistics', component:MyStatisticsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path:'my-acquired-leads', component:MyAcquiredLeadsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path:'login', component:LoginComponent },
  { path:'logout', component:LogoutComponent },
  { path:'pass-forget', component:PassForgetComponent },

  // default
  { path:'', redirectTo: '/my-company/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },

];

const routesChild: Routes = [

  // Child route for my company
  { path:'my-company', component:MyCompanyComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], children:[
    { path:'',component:DashboardComponent },
    { path:'dashboard',component:DashboardComponent },
    { path:'opening-hours',component:OpeningHoursComponent },
    { path:'offers',component:OffersComponent },
    { path:'personal-information',component:PersonalInformationComponent },
  ]},


];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes),RouterModule.forChild(routesChild) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

 // the authGuard service
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
    if (!this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

When I log, I have the header and the sidebar but I dont have the content, the router-outlet does not seem to work. If I refresh, it's work well. It's the same when I logout, the login page is empty but if I refresh the page it's work fine.

Why the router-outlet is empty after login and logout ? (I have no error)

Comment: how is your router config ??

Comment: I edit the main question

Comment: Can we see the AuthGuardService? You probably have sometihng async happening there, and thats why the first time its empty

Comment: I edit to add authguard